# Is it possible to add List<string> values dynamically in one line of code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, list

I have a project where I'm getting values from formview fields as strings (40+ fields).  I would like to reduce the amount of lines in my code and would like to combine adding list values into a single line of code for each string value I'm gathering from my formview.

My code snip is:

```
...
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

string str1 = e.NewValues["value1"].ToString();
myList.Add(str1);
string str2 = e.NewValues["value2"].ToString();
myList.Add(str2);
string str3 = e.NewValues["value3"].ToString();
myList.Add(str3);
string str4 = e.NewValues["value4"].ToString();
myList.Add(str4);
...
```

Is it possible to add these strings in just one line of code something like:

```
myList.Add(string str1 = e.NewValues["value1"].ToString());
```

or

```
myList.Add((string) something... not getting the correct format.
```

I have done something similar with sql parameters
ie --

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("ENTRY", OleDbType.VarChar) 
 { 
   Value = ENTRY,
   Direction = ParameterDirection.Input 
 });
```

-- but I have searched numerous ways of trying to do this and nothing turns up. I'm not sure if I'm just not searching for it correctly or if it is just not possible?

Comment: myList.Add(e.NewValues["value1"].ToString());

Comment: Ugh!  I was thinking way too hard and overcomplicating it. All of your responses work. Thank you for your quick responses.

Comment: what is NewValues ? list?

Comment: `myList =e.NewValues.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToList();`

Comment: NewValues is an event arg off of my FormView.  I just needed to build a list of values to pass to an update sproc.

Comment: NewValues is a dictionary so like this - List<string> mylist = e.NewValues.Values.ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
myList.Add(e.NewValues["value1"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>
{
   e.NewValues["value1"].ToString(),
   e.NewValues["value2"].ToString()
   //etc...
};
```

using an [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) will let you build the object up when you initialize it.

For example, if you have a class:

```
class Test
{
   string test1 { get; set; }
   int test2 { get; set; }
}
```

you can initialize it like:

```
Test tester = new Test{ test1 = "some string", test2 = 5 };
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using Linq?

Something like:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

myList.AddRange(e.NewValues.ToList().Select(s => s.ToString());
```

or

```
e.NewValues.ToList().ForEach(v => 
                        {
                          //can add additional manipulation or If clause here
                          //if you have some exclusions
                          myList.Add(v.ToString())
                         });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
myList.AddRange(
   new[]{  
        e.NewValues["value1"].ToString(),   
        e.NewValues["value2"].ToString()  
});
```

or use the inline assignment:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>
{
   e.NewValues["value1"].ToString(),
   e.NewValues["value2"].ToString()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

NewValues is a dictionary so like this will work in a one liner:

```
 List<string> mylist = e.NewValues.Values.ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.ToString());
```

Update:

What NewValues returns is a orderedDictionary so inside your eventHandler place this code:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

foreach (DictionaryEntry item in e.NewValues)
{
    mylist.Add(item.Value.ToString());
}
```

or if mylist is a class member variable then just the foreach loop will populate the list.

Comment: ToList is not an option after values but is if ...Values.ToString().ToList()... is added but then it doesn't return the field values I'm looking for.  The FormView also has labels and dropdowns that I'm getting values from and updating a record in a db.  If I could get all of my control values from the formview in one line that would be awesome! I'm using '(Object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)' - if there is a better way, I'm open.

Comment: @acjohnson72 Just edited based on your comment hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table>
<tr>    <td>    <asp:TextBox ID="txxt" runat="server" />    </td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td>    <asp:Button ID="btn" Text="test" runat="server" style="width: 36px" />    </td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td>  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdntest" runat="server" />    </td>    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

.

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click

    Dim s As String = ""
    s = txxt.Text
    s = s + ","
    hdntest.Value = hdntest.Value + s
    txxt.Text = hdntest.Value

End Sub
```